# swift array empty in view but contains data in viewModel

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a function in my ViewModel file that adds data into an array, I can print this array out in my viewModel file and see all the data. But in my view file when I call the array like viewModel.array it appears that there is no data in them. How do I change my code so that I can access the array in the view? Also the fetchConvos() function is being called in the init so the users array should get updated.

viewModel file

```
class MessageViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var users = [User]()
    func fetchConvos(){
        service.getConversations() { users in
            self.users = users              
        }
    }
```

view

```
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = MessageViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        if let index = viewModel.users.firstIndex(of: user) {
            ....
```

Here index never gets assigned because users array is empty.

Comment: This is the same issue you posted in [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74844321/array-keeps-resetting-after-function).

Comment: @HangarRash that question was about accessing array values in the same function, this one Im asking how to access the array value in a different file.

Comment: It's the same issue. The data is being loaded asynchronously but you are trying to access the data long before it gets loaded.

Comment: @HangarRash whats the fix then? I understand that you are saying data is loaded asynchronously. You never proposed a solution or example to solve this.

Comment: Use StateObject, not ObservedObject. The issue you’re having is that you’re accessing the array before it gets populated.

Comment: @cora Will my code work with this small change? Or should I implement the onRecieve as described below?

Comment: @cora that didnt work, array still empty

Comment: @HangarRash see dude that how a question is answered look at frugals response

Comment: @swswswsw you must know the difference between StateObject and ObservedObject.

Comment: It’s hard to say what else need to be changed because your code is incomplete. Need the rest of the view’s body.

Answer (score -2):

You have to subscribe to the @Published property wrapper. Therefore you use the `.onReceive(`.

To make things clear, here is a little example with comments:

```
class MessageViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var users = [String]()
    func fetchConvos() {
        self.users = ["Name 1", "Name 2"]
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = MessageViewModel()
    
    @State var name: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(name)
            // onReceice is to subscribe to @Published property wrappers
            .onReceive(viewModel.$users, perform: { users in
                name = users.first ?? "No users!"
            })
            .onAppear { // when the view appears we creating our users in the model, thanks our onReceive subscription, we can adapt our views justs by changing the @State property wrapper
                viewModel.fetchConvos()
            }
        
        // This button changes the view itself
        Button {
            changeName()
        } label: {
            Label("Give the user a new name", systemImage: "plus")
        }
        .buttonStyle(.bordered)
        
        // onChange is for subscribing to @State property wrappers
        .onChange(of: name) { newValue in
            let newName = newValue
            print("new user name:", newName)
            viewModel.users[0] = newName // here we notify the model, that the view changed
            #warning("Make sure the users array is not empty")
        }

    }
    func changeName() {
        name = "New name"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so if I have 2 variables that I want to get data for from the array do I have to use the onRecieve and onAppear twice for each one of them? Or can I just do this for the first var

Comment: You have to do it for each of them. With the subscription, the code in the closure (inside the {} brackets) after the onReceive oder onChange gets executed every time this variable changed, which is defined in the () brackets.